# Trigger a model update from view in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If the view (e.g the value in a text input) is changed by an external javascript, it will not be reflected in the model.

How can I trigger a model update (to read back all binding values from the view).

P.S: for some reasons, manually setting the model value is not an option for me, I just need to call the same function that is called when user is typing in the text box.

Comment: Do you have any control over the external script that changes the value?

Comment: Actually, yes, but as the project will gradually expand, I don't like to impose artificial constraints/guidlines for javascripts: just plug in whatever suits you and we'll all be happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are changing the value of an element, for example input, that uses `ng-model` it should suffice to trigger the element's 'change' event.

jQuery:

```
$('#input').val('new value').trigger('change');
```

No jQuery:

```
var input = document.querySelector('#input');
input.value = 'new value';

var event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
event.initEvent('change', true, false);
input.dispatchEvent(event);
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/IFb8OmegaGAAniy9ttn5?p=preview